# Call Azure Function from Data Factory using Managed Service Identity

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I want my Data Factory's Web Activity to authenticate to my Azure Function using MSI (Managed Service Identity), so I don't have to include the API key in the Web-URL.

What type of resource string do I need to enter here in the configuration section of the Web Activity:

[image: dialogue]

I tried:

- https://myfunctionapp.azurewebsites.net/
- https://myfunctionapp.azurewebsites.net/api/myfunction

but none worked. The pipeline activity times out after a few minutes with the error "Error calling the endpoint".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue, but using https://management.azure.com/ as the resource string worked for me in terms of making MSI function, but after a bunch of testing it seems to me as though the HTTPTrigger still requires a key in either the URI or the header.

Both of these websites are good resources:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-managed-service-identity
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-service-identity/services-support-msi

Comment: To summarize - Azure Functions can consume other Azure services using its own Managed Identity however it doesn't support being invoked (ex: HttpTrigger) via Managed Identity of other Azure Services (ex: Another Function etc.)