# What is the "Resource" when setting up a call to REST API from ADF with Managed Indentity

Tags: azure, azure-adf

I have created an Azure Function App and I can call it from browser with a URL similar to this:

```
https://myfunctionblahblh.appserviceenvironment.net/api/names/Peter/TGIF?code=my_function_app_key_Goes_Here
```

Now I want to call it from my ADF pipeline: So I dropped a Web activity and set it up like this so far:

[image]

So my question is what is the "Resource" that it is asking for? Also in the URL that for company reasons I have blacked out, imagine I have copied the URL of the function I pasted above, is that correct ?

Comment: I think you need https://management.azure.com/ for Resource.  See this description https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity#managed-identity  .  But you may want to look at this because it may not work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50835887/call-azure-function-from-data-factory-using-managed-service-identity?rq=1  but maybe that has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Resource` field is where you specify the uri for the service that you want to send the token to. In the case of authenticating with managed identities, you will want to send it to "https://management.azure.com/". However, if your function is already authenticating with the "code" query string parameter, you may be able to set the `Authentication` field to "None".

Comment: Thanks, Anonymous authentication worked because the code was there.